Bound an integral by a function with an appropriate decay
I am reading a result about estimate for the heat equation with right hand side and there is a step of computation I don't quite get. Let $\nu \in (0,1)$, then
$$\int_0^t \frac{1}{1 + s^\nu} \frac{1}{1 + t - s}ds \le C \frac{1 + \log_+t}{ 1 + t^\nu}$$
where $\log_+t = \max\{0, \log t\}$ and $C$ might depend on $\nu$. I tried to explicitly compute the integral using partial fraction decomposition but the result is quite ugly and I don't reach the same bound.

We prove that $C = 2$ is valid.
(1) $t > 1$
Let
$$f(v) := (1 + t^v)\int_0^t \frac{1}{1 + s^v} \frac{1}{1 + t - s}\, \mathrm{d} s.$$
We have
$$f'(v) = \int_0^t \left(\frac{t^v\ln t}{(1 + s^v)(1 + t - s)} - \frac{(1 + t^v)s^v\ln s}{(1+s^v)^2(1 + t - s)}\right)\,\mathrm{d} s
$$
$$\ge \int_0^t \left(\frac{t^v\ln t}{(1 + s^v)(1 + t - s)} - \frac{(1 + t^v)s^v\ln t}{(1+s^v)^2(1 + t - s)}\right)\,\mathrm{d} s$$
$$= \int_0^t \frac{(t^v - s^v)\ln t}{(1+s^v)^2(1+t-s)}\,\mathrm{d} s \ge 0.$$
Thus, we have
$$f(v) \le f(1) = (1 + t)\int_0^t \frac{1}{1 + s} \frac{1}{1 + t - s}\, \mathrm{d} s = (1 + t)\cdot \frac{2\ln(1 + t)}{2 + t}
\le 2(1 + \ln t).$$
The desired result follows.
(2) $0 < t \le 1$
We have
$$\int_0^t \frac{1}{1 + s^v} \frac{1}{1 + t - s}\, \mathrm{d} s
\le \int_0^1 1\, \mathrm{d} s = 1,$$
and
$$\frac{1 + \log_+t}{ 1 + t^v}
\ge \frac12.$$
The desired result follows.

Nice answer, thank you very much!

@Falcon You are welcome.
